# How to emulate a KWin effect by command line?

Tags: command-line, scripting, kde, window, kwin

I would like to apply the **Toogle Invert Effect** when I start my system.

So, I need to know how to call this KWin effect using the terminal.

OBS.: I'd tried `xte "keydown Meta_L" "key i" "keyup Meta_L"`, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The effect itself does not seem to do anything on my computer, but I think you can enable/disable it through dbus in this way:

Enable

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.KWin /Effects org.kde.kwin.Effects.loadEffect string:"invert"
```

Disable

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.kde.KWin /Effects org.kde.kwin.Effects.unloadEffect string:"invert"
```